# Setting language of iOS keyboard extension

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I am developing a Keyboard extension for iOS. In Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboards, the language is shown as `English`. Where to change this language?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In keyboard extension's Info.plist, change "NSExtension" -> "NSExtensionAttributes" -> "PrimaryLanguage" to the desired language.

[image: Image showing the Info.plist]

Comment: And if you want it to say "Multiple languages" set it to "mul"